# Add monitor mode on Raspberry Pi 3B by using Nexmon

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, monitor

I want to add monitor mode on Raspberry Pi 3B (Not 3B+) by using Nexmon but failed and says "Operation not supported"

I am completely a beginner and following this [website](https://github.com/seemoo-lab/nexmon/blob/master/README.md)
(Build patches for bcm43430a1 on the RPI3/Zero W or bcm434355c0 on the RPI3+/RPI4 using Raspbian (recommended) part)

Any advice will be much appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: Hm, your Question is not exactly Code-related, you might get better answers on the StackExchange Site for Raspberry-related Questions [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thank you for your advise. I'll visit StackExchange site and look up my question :)